# Exception handling with async delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, async-await

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I'm sure it's something stupid, but I could use some extra eyes to figure out what it is. I'm trying to create a worker service that you can assign a work action delegate to. When I try to catch the exception thrown by the work action delegate the handler isn't invoked. I think it is because my action is actually an async method that returns Task and it isn't being awaited. But how am I supposed to know that the delegate is async? Why does C# let me assign a method that returns a Task to a action variable that is supposed to return void?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
[Fact]
public async Task CanCatchExceptions() {
    var worker = new Worker {
        WorkAction = async item => await Throws()
    };
    worker.DoWork(new WorkItem { Id = 1 });
}

public class Worker {
    // would prefer to keep work action simple and not require a Task.
    public Action<WorkItem> WorkAction { get; set; }

    public void DoWork(WorkItem item) {
        try {
            WorkAction(item);
        } catch {
            Debug.WriteLine("Handled");
        }
    }
}

public class WorkItem {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public async Task Throws() {
    throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

Comment: So one option is to set WorkAction = item => Throws().Wait() but I still don't understand why I am allowed to assign a variable of type Action<WorkItem> with a variable of type Func<WorkItem, Task>.

Comment: I think Stephen's answer addresses this. But to reiterate: the language has special rules to allow this. It will implicitly allow `async Task` to be equivalent to `async void`, which is what happens in your case, allowing the lambda expression to be used for the `Action<WorkItem>` delegate type. But note that this conversion doesn't change the behavior of the `async` method; it still returns at the first `await` statement, and so unless awaited (which you can't if it's `void`), the caller can (and usually does) complete before the `async` method does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does C# let me assign a method that returns a Task to a action variable that is supposed to return void?

Because `async void` is a legitimate use case for async event handlers, that's why the compiler permits the void returning `Action<T>` and doesn't complain. Once you're aware of that fact, you can explicitly use a `Func<Task>` which will create the desired `Task` returning method overload.

As you say to you prefer to keep work action *"simple"* and not require a task, consider supplying an async overload which will behave properly with the async control flow:

```
public Func<WorkItem, Task> WorkAsync { get; set; }

public async Task WorkAsync(WorkItem item)
{
      try
      {
            await WorkAsync(item)
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           // Handle
      }
}
```

Note this may be in a completely different class (seperate the async worker with the sync one), as per your choice.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 4):

Lambdas without return values may be cast to a task-returning method (e.g., `Func<Task>`) or a void-returning method (e.g., `Action`). Note that when casting to a void-returning method, the actual method for that lambda is an `async void` method, with all the problems that come along with `async void` methods. I describe some of the problems of `async void` in my [best practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); one of them is that you can't catch exceptions with `try`.

The best option is to change your work items to return `Task`, which is a much more natural representation of asynchronous methods.